# Why does something work as part of a function but not as an immediate command?

Tags: octave, sigmoid

My sigmoid implementation seperately in a function works, but inserting the code directly in the command window gives an error.

My sigmoid function:

```
function g = sigmoid(z)

g=1/(1+(e.^(-z)));

end
```

In my command prompt, I called:

```
h=sigmoid (x*t)
```

This gives the result correctly.

But if I enter the program directly, it displays an error:

```
>> plot(1/(1+(e.^(-(x*t)))))

error: operator /: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 1x1, op2 is 100x3)
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Cannot reproduce.

Comment: It needs to say `./` in both cases.

Comment: Cris Luengo already gave the solution. And I really doubt that it "worked" in the function. I guess you called sigmoid with scalars and later plot with vectors. You really have to first learn the basics (scalars, vectors, matrices additions, multiplications and so on)